# Changing class in the ng-repeat using the index value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-class

Here I have a div in the ng-repeat

```
<div   ng-class="{div0f:result.subscribed==omega.harish,div0g:!result.subscribed==omega.harish}" id="mecota0f" 
          ng-click="omega.harish=!result.subscribed" >
```

Now here result.subscribed is a boolean value coming from the services and omega.harish is my simple  boolean variable
the class of this div will be according to the  result.subscribed value

Now I also want to change the active class of the one of the div created in the ng-repeat but the class of other created divs are kept getting affected.

```js
var app = angular.module('subscribeWho', ['ngResource']);
app.controller('mysubscribeWho', ['subscriberFactory',
  function(subscriberFactory) {

    var self = this;


    subscriberFactory.get({}, function(subscriberFactory) {
      self.subscriberdata = subscriberFactory.user;
    });


    self.harish = false;
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="border-forpb" class="col-sm-12 panel panel-default" ng-app="subscribeWho">
  <div class="panel-body" id="artle_panel_body" ng-controller="mysubscribeWho as omega">
    <div ng-repeat="result in omega.subscriberdata">
      <div ng-class="{div0f:result.subscribed==omega.harish,div0g:!result.subscribed==omega.harish}" id="mecota0f" ng-click="omega.harish=!result.subscribed">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Small Details When the div is being clicked the states of the above two classes div0f and div0g interchanges for the particular div

Comment: the active one becomes inactive and vice -versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing outer scope `omega.harish` value which is common for all items in the ngRepeat. Instead create local scope copy of `omega.harish` with `ngInit` directive:

```
<div ng-repeat="result in omega.subscriberdata">
    <div ng-class="{div0f:result.subscribed==harish,div0g:!result.subscribed==harish}" id="mecota0f" 
        ng-init="harish = omega.harish"
        ng-click="harish=!result.subscribed">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot !!!, It worked It just that Being a newBie in angularjs , I was not been able to render this mistake

Comment: But this has One problem that It changes only one class but doesn't affect the other one on click

Comment: What do you mean "affect the other one on click"?

Comment: When I click on the Div with the class Div0f It changes to the Div0g, But I click on the Div with the Class Div0g It doesnt changes it active class

Comment: thanks With some of the minor changes Dfsq Your code began to work as per my requirement